# Should we edit questions to use the chess replayer?

Tags: discussion, pgn-viewer

Now that we have a chess replayer, there are a bunch of questions (like [this one](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/438/478)) that have ugly plain PGNs in them, should we edit these to display to display them with the replayer?

And, what about incomplete games (e.g openings with just few moves), or FEN positions? Should these be edited too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with some exceptions. In general, it's a service to passing visitors, in that they don't have to play blindfold. Isolated FEN positions and short or long games should definitely be edited.

However, there are [some answers with numerous variations](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/1821/652). While the linked example is a fine answer, I don't think it would benefit from a replayer for each individual variation. At that point reading it would be a chore, particularly on mobile devices.

Thus, I think the answer should be "almost all, but only to enhance".

Answer (score 8):

I would say YES, if you have the time, go ahead and edit the question to use the replayer.  It is so much better.